# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error with small piece of code

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

i sometimes get the above mentioned error, i know its due to the following code but dont see what could be cause, as im still quite new to C.

```
struct Point playerPosition;
int counter = 0;
do {
    playerPosition.x = rand() % mapLength;
    playerPosition.y = rand() % mapHeight;
    counter++;
    printf("The current tile that is being tried is: %c\n", map[playerPosition.x][playerPosition.y]);
} while((counter < (mapLength*mapHeight)) && ((map[playerPosition.x][playerPosition.y] == '#') || (map[playerPosition.x][playerPosition.y] == 'P')));
printf("A tile was found at %d %d, with the tile being %c\n", playerPosition.x, playerPosition.y, map[playerPosition.x][playerPosition.y]);
```

Comment: where are `maplength`/`mapheight` defined, and how do they relate to `map`?

Comment: As well as `struct Point` (though we can probably guess at its declaration) See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code snippet that `map` is defined. That could certainly cause a segfault.

Comment: Data types/declarations are at least as important as code.  You should include them.

Answer (score 0):

Some parts are missing in your example code but the problem will most probably be in accessing `map`. Also the definition of `rand()` is importent. If it delivers values between -1 and 1 you will end up with a segmentation fault.

Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) and other tools to get more information, what's the cause for the segmentation fault.